# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-csv-import'

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2

I need to import [vue-csv-import](https://github.com/jgile/vue-csv-import/tree/vue2) for vue 2. Added it using this command,

```
npm install vue-csv-import@3.3.8
```

package.json has updated has this,

```
"dependencies": {
   "vue-csv-import": "^3.3.8",
```

package-lock.json has updated too..

```
"vue-csv-import": {
      "version": "3.3.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-csv-import/-/vue-csv-import-3.3.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-zYunaurbiOSd5zYuSFJDLo4jrQq2Kin2gbATdjSsDXlOGS4mTjLf0eIFhuIeyNiHwjCKLKaNGaQIILYxT5DwpA==",
      "requires": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "core-js": "^3.8.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "mime-types": "^2.1.27",
        "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.12"
      }
    },
```

I tried `npm cache clean --force` too. And I'm running server with this command.

```
npm run serve
```

And import like,

```
import { VueCsvImport } from 'vue-csv-import';
```

But getting this error finally

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-csv-import'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the component author has a little _whoopsie doodle_™ in the some of the vue2 versions where the component is not actually built.

You can try an older version like `3.3.5` or newer like `3.3.10` which has the component built and available in the `/dist` directory

```
npm install vue-csv-import@3.3.10
```

alternatively, if you need that version, you could try building it yourself, but that adds to the complexity.

By this [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/4smjx) which is working we can find version '3.3.5'

Comment: Thanks mate for the clear explanation and added the correct version which worked for me